# R: sample sizes and differences in proportions

Tags: r

This question is part methodology, part coding

I have a population in which, given that no one started with pain, I found that 13% of people developed pain (95% CI: 9, 18). In other words, expected proportion = 0.13.

I want to develop a table or graph which can tell me this:

If I had a study of size N (N= 10, 15, 20, etc.), **what proportion of individuals would have to develop pain in order to detect a significant difference from the expected proportion** (0.13)? Alpha = 0.05, power =0.8. I don't need the code to makes a table/graph, but how to find these numbers!

Obviously in smaller studies (e.g. n=10), one would need a larger difference for significance. I'm sorry for the lack of code, I was trying to figure this out in G*Power but would prefer to do so in R. Thanks!!

Comment: This is not the right place to ask `statistics` questions. But see if this helps: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/AnesShortCourse/HypothesisTestingPart1.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post my older code which might need some tweaking (problem with small `n`,...):

```
library(pwr)

estimatedP <- 0.13
estES <- pwr.p.test(n=150, sig.level=0.05, power=0.8, alternative="greater")$h
```

`estES` contains effect size for difference of two proportions. Your proportion is `estimatedP`.  There are two options now. Your `estimatedP` is lower than then or is higher than the proportion of the second group. You're looking for `EShigh` (proportion which is higher than 13%):

```
ESlow <- function(lowProp, estimP, estimES){
 # Estimates lower proportion
 2*asin(sqrt(estimP)) -2*asin(sqrt(lowProp))  - estimES
}

EShigh <- function(highProp, estimP, estimES){
 # Estimates higher proportion
 2*asin(sqrt(highProp)) -2*asin(sqrt(estimP))  - estimES
}
```

In the next step corresponding proportion from effect size is computed:

```
highP <- uniroot(EShigh, c(0,1), tol=0.0001, estimES=estES, estimP=estimatedP)$root
lowP  <- uniroot(ESlow , c(0,1), tol=0.0001, estimES=estES, estimP=estimatedP)$root
```

Look at proportions:

```
highP # Proportion > 0.205 to be detectable
lowP  # Proportion < 0.07 to be detectable
```

You can check that the effect size has the almost identical magnitude but different direction:

```
ES.h(lowP, estimatedP)
ES.h(estimatedP, highP)
```